# I want to make my div increase in size while I hold down the mouse using Javascript

Tags: javascript

[Pic of RGB-light] I want to make this RGB light bigger when you are holding down your mouse with a pointer down event in javascript. I have tried a lot of different solutions, but nothing works. Maybe some of you could write your solution to my problem?

Thanks in advance.

```
// Getting acess to the HTMl elements
let clickOnPic = document.getElementById("background-picture"); 
let lightEl = document.getElementById("RGB-container");

let body = document.querySelector("body");
// Setting the light element to not show at the start
lightEl.style.display = "none";

// Setting the lights rotation
const lightRotation =  {transform: "rotate(360deg)"}

// Setting how fast and how many times the light is going to spin
const lightTiming = {
    duration: 2500,
    iterations: Infinity
}

// Function for attaching the light element to the cursor
function attachToMouse (e) {
    
    // Getting the cursors position
    let mouseX = e.clientX;
    let mouseY = e.clientY;

    // Making the element being at the center of the cursor
    let lightX = mouseX - (lightEl.offsetWidth / 2);
    let lightY = mouseY - (lightEl.offsetHeight / 2);

    // Setting the element to the cursor position
    lightEl.style.left = lightX + "px";
    lightEl.style.top = lightY + "px"; 
}

// Eventlistener for when the user clicks on the screen to display the light element
document.addEventListener("pointerup", function(event) {
    
    // Checking if the light element is not displayed, and if it's not displayed we are displaying the light element
    if(lightEl.style.display === "none"){
        
        // Display the light
        lightEl.style.display = "block" 
        
        // Make the rotate animation
        lightEl.animate(lightRotation, lightTiming); 

        // Make the cursor disapear
        body.style.cursor = "none";

        attachToMouse(event);
         
    }
    else { // If the light element is shown, do nothing
        return
    }
})

// Eventlistener for attaching the light element to the cursor
document.addEventListener("pointermove", attachToMouse)
```

Comment: add html markup for it as well

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.